# Versioning the js files using browserify to prevent client using old js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browser-cache, browserify

I have started to use browserify instead of requirejs,
on requirejs i could use urlArgs in config and give new version number when i changed the js codes. so that browser won't use the previously cached js file.

I couldnt find how to add this. Here is my current gulp file,

```
.....

gulp.task('browserify', function () {
    var browserified = transform(function(filename) {
        var b = browserify(filename);
        return b.bundle();
    });

    return gulp.src(['./js/main.js'])
        .pipe(browserified)
        // .pipe(uglify()) // commented out on testing environment.
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
});

....


gulp.task('html', function() {
    return gulp.src('./src/index.html')
        .pipe(htmlreplace({
            'css': 'css/main.css',
            'js': {
                src: [
                    ... // infrastructural js files / plugins
                    'js/main.js'
                ]
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
.....


gulp.task('default', ['browserify', 'html'], function (callback) {
    callback();
    console.log('\nPlaced optimized files in ' + chalk.magenta('dist/\n'));
});
```

i have tried to add ?v=0.01 to main.js inside the htmlreplace task  but it produced

```
js/main.js?v=0.1
```

instead of

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

We use [gulp-buster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-buster) on all files to cachebust all references to static assets. I suppose you could set it up to be a bit more specific about what files it busts.

Comment: I couldnt manage the code with watch but i made it work without the watch. But how can i be sure that my files wont be cached? because it didnt add any versioning parameter.

Comment: return gulp.src(['./js/main.js'])
        .pipe(browserified)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))
        .pipe(bust())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));;